# Is multiple Aegis of Immortal possible in Dota2?

Tags: dota-2

In the *Warcraft3 DotA*, it is possible to have multiple **Aegis of Immortality** by having killed *Roshan* and nobody picking up the **Aegis**, thus when *Roshan* respawns after 10mins it will still be there and there you'll have two Aegis.

Is this still possible in Dota2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to try this out myself by playing with AI bots and used *Ursa Warrior* to solo Roshan early on.

The result, **No you can't.** When Roshan respawns, he reclaims the Aegis, either from your inventory or the untaken one laying on the ground.

Comment: What if you pick up the aegis right before Roshan respawns?

Comment: @Moshe Roshan still reclaims it.

Answer (score -1):

you cant get more than one aegis in the game

because in-game mechs . roshan is only respawn once, but if your aegis still exists but in certain time roshan wanted to respawn. then it will vanish and in next battle you might get cheese